# Is it possible to colored one building?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to colored one building ?

I would like to highlight this building on the map among the others

I don't know how can I use:

building-extrusion -> Fill-extrusion by building ID

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [filter](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/) and do something like

`filter: ['==', 'building_id', YOUR_ID]`

then set the `fill-extrusion-color` [like so](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-extrusion-floorplan/)